# LinkedIn "The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumer Key: 'value of consumer key' "

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an application in asp.net c#. 
In which i can post anything and that post will also be posted on users own LinkedIn account.  I am getting exception

> The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. consumer
>   Key:Consumer key value from responseReader = new
>   StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

What is the meaning of this exception?

Note: I am setting Client API Key as consumer key And webRequest Header contains

```
oauth_token,realm,oauth_consumer_key,oauth_signature_method,oauth_token_secret,
`oauth_signature`, `oauth_timestamp`, `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_verifier`, `oauth_version=1.0`
```

But verifier and token secret is blank.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

There can be various events which can cause an access token to become invalid:

**1. Life of access token expires:** Generally, lifetime of linkedin access token is 60 days. In case this time period is elapsed, the access token expires and becomes invalid.

**2. User revokes permissions to your application from LinkedIn.com:** If user has revoked the permissions to your application, then also access token becomes invalid.

In both the cases, your application then needs to take the user through the authorization flow again.

Also verify that the access token you are using for API call is a valid token.

For reference: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens